# Using partitionBy() and persist() in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to optimize my script doing a **hush partitioning** and using persist() in spark 2.1 but running my code I have an error that I don't understand.

The code is:

```
rdd = sc.textFile("path").map(lambdal:l.split(";"))

rdd_pair=rdd.map(lambda a: (a[0], a)).PartitionBy(920).persist()

rdd_pair=rdd_pair.combineByKey(lambda v:[v],lambda x,y:x+[y],lambda x,y:x+y)

def fn(input_bag):
    output=[]
    loc0 = input_bag[0]
    for loc in input_bag[1:]:
        output.append((loc0[2],loc[2]))
        loc0 = loc
    return output

data=rdd1.map(lambda k: (k[0], fn(k[1]))).persist()

data=data.flatMap(lambda x: map(lambda e: (e, x[0]), x[1])).map(lambda x: (x[0],1)).reduceByKey(lambda p,q: p+q)

data.map(lambda x:",".join(map(str,x))).saveAsTextFile(Path)
```

The **error** is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/wrjx9579/test1.py", line 12, in <module>
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

  File "/opt/application/Spark2/current/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark
/context.py", line 118, in __ init __

  File "/opt/application/Spark2/current/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark
/context.py", line 179, in _do_init

  File "/opt/application/Spark2/current/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 246, in _initialize_context

  File "/opt/application/Spark2/current/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __ call__

  File "/opt/application/Spark2/current/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.

: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; 
Host Details : local host is: "..."; destination host is: "...":8032;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand the logic behind the `fn` function and hence cannot validate my output. Spark uses `HashPartitioning` by default. See [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala)

Please find below the code that gives output for the following input.

Input:

```
1;1
2;1
3;1
4;2
5;2
6;2
```

Output:

```
>>> sc = spark.sparkContext
>>> 
>>> rdd = sc.textFile("/Users/pavithranrao/Desktop/test.csv").map(lambda l:l.split(";"))
>>> 
>>> rdd_pair=rdd.map(lambda a: (a[0], a)).partitionBy(2).persist()
>>> rdd_pair.count()
6
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> rdd_pair.foreach(lambda x : print(x))
(u'2', [u'2', u'1'])
(u'4', [u'4', u'2'])
(u'6', [u'6', u'2'])
(u'1', [u'1', u'1'])
(u'3', [u'3', u'1'])
(u'5', [u'5', u'2'])
>>> 
>>> rdd_pair_comb = rdd_pair.combineByKey(lambda v:[v], lambda x, y : x+[y], lambda x ,y : x+y)
>>> rdd_pair_comb.foreach(lambda x : print(x))
(u'2', [[u'2', u'1']])
(u'4', [[u'4', u'2']])
(u'6', [[u'6', u'2']])
(u'1', [[u'1', u'1']])
(u'3', [[u'3', u'1']])
(u'5', [[u'5', u'2']])
>>> 
>>> def fn(input_bag):
...     output=[]
...     loc0 = input_bag[0]
...     for loc in input_bag[1:]:
...         output.append((loc0[2],loc[2]))
...         loc0 = loc
...     return output
... 
>>> data = rdd_pair_comb.map(lambda k: (k[0], fn(k[1]))).persist()
>>> data.count()
6
>>> 
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> data.foreach(lambda x : print(x))
(u'4', [])
(u'6', [])
(u'1', [])
(u'3', [])
(u'5', [])
```

Hope this helps!